# Power Automate Web API GET Failing Intermittently

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, webapi, power-automate, dataverse

I am seeing intermittent, buggy behavior where *sometimes* I can [GET a flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/web-api#update-a-cloud-flow) with the `/api/data/v9.1/workflows(FLOWGUID)` endpoint, but other times it cannot find it. Below is an example of the behavior. Each query was run within moments of each other, using the same access token and Dataverse environment URL.

The targeted flow was created using the API, but I have also seen the behavior with manually created flows.

**Workflow with GUID is returned with `/api/data/v9.1/workflows?$filter=category eq 5` query.**
[image]

**When copy/pasting the previous flow GUID into `/api/data/v9.1/workflows(FLOWGUID)`, it cannot find it.**
[image]

Comment: uhm, to be honest I never triggered a Flow from code in that way, I use that endpoint to trigger classic workflows (category equals 0) but with a POST call, not a GET. I quickly searched and I didn't find a doc page on how to do it, are you following some official doc or blog post?

Comment: Sorry, I should've included a link to the documentation. I added it above and here it is. They don't have a GET example of retrieving a single flow but you can see an example of the endpoint in a PATCH update request.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/web-api#update-a-cloud-flow

Comment: if I understood correctly you just want to retrieve the details of the flow and not executing it, right? do you see a property called "workflowid" in your first query in addition to "workflowidunique"? because "workflowidunique" is marked as an internal field and is different from "workflowid" value

Comment: to add some context to my previous comment, when you query dataverse using that syntax - entityname(entityid) - the syntax expect the id of the entity, if for example the entity is account, it will be - accounts(a732983c-71bc-49ec-b920-6c665467684d) - and the entityid should match accountid in this example